# VLC 2.0: can't enable UPnP support

Tags: macos, osx-lion, vlc-media-player, upnp

I'm attempting to use VLC 2.0.1 (Intel 64 bit) to connect to a UPnP server (Serviio 0.6.2 on OS X Snow Leopard).

I've tried to enable the feature by right clicking the "Universal Plug 'n Play" node in the LOCAL NETWORK section of the Main Window.  While I am able to select 'Enable', the setting doesn't seem to 'stick'.  Moreover, UPnP isn't listed in the Playlist > Service discovery section of the preferences.  The 'Service discovery modules' is currently set to `upnp_intel:sap`.

I am able to connect to the UPnP server with my Samsung TV, so I know that the service works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this thread: [Upnp not showing any servers](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=99449).  EyeTV has interfering with VLC.  Once I removed EyeTV, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found I had to quit the Sonos app in order to enable UPnP in VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Guys hot trick for windows. I saw several post saying that this feature is missing or that it wasnt more avaliable. After several 1,5 years i was able to figure out what happened. The information is just hidden. Go to reproduction list and move your mouse very slowly from top to bottom. Magically will appear the mouse drag. Just click on it and you can resize the window and everything will appear.All UNPN options are there. It was never discontinued or removed. Cheers. LP